# JS: how to check a button was disabled?

Tags: javascript

I want to check the button pressed or not pressed. How do I can do it?

I've already tried to do, but it doesn't work. Here's my code.

```
<button onClick="getButton()" id="button2">Disable</button>
<button id="button1">OK</button>
<script>
function getButton() {
document.getElementById('button1').disabled=true;
}

if (getElementById('button1').disabled=true == true) {
document.write("The button was disabled");
}
else {
document.write("No, the button didn't disable");
}
```

How to check it with if-else statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
function getButton() { 
document.getElementById('button1').disabled=true; 
 document.write("The button was disabled");
}
```

Comment: I prefer to check it with if-else. :) 

But your variation is true too.

Answer (score 0):

In your conditional statement, `getElementById('button1').disabled=true` should be `getElementById('button1').disabled`. The former will always return `true`, so you're checking if `true` equals `true`...