# How to enable a button when other three are disabled?

Tags: javascript

I need to create a function which enables a fourth button when the first three are disabled. This is what I got and works like a charm:

```js
function apagaMobile() {
    document.getElementById("mobile").disabled = true;
}

function apagaCell() {
    document.getElementById("cell").disabled = true;
}

function apagaSmart() {
    document.getElementById("smart").disabled = true;
}
```

This works in three buttons with the named IDs. So I need a last function that enables this button when the first three are disabled.

```html
<button type="button" class="resolve center-block" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" id="answer" disabled>Answer the question</button>
```

Comment: What does your function look like that enables the last button?

Comment: I don't have any, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Check the state of the other two buttons in each function. If all three are disabled, set the `disabled` property of the fourth button to `false`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Can you give me an example?

Comment: `if (element.disabled) doSomething();`

Comment: If you want a full answer, provide a [mre], showing all of the HTML you are working with. But really, it's just combining [JS: how to check a button was disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19570998/215552) and what you already know, which is how to disable a button.

Comment: Did you try `document.getElementById("answer").disabled = false`?

Comment: What ideas did you try?

Comment: If you want to preserve those three functions, then you can put inside each of them this code: `mobile.disabled && cell.disabled && smart.disabled && (answer.disabled = !1);` But @mplungjan suggested a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would delegate and count

```js
const container = document.getElementById('apagaDiv');
const buttons = [...container.querySelectorAll('.apaga')];
container.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains('apaga')) {
    tgt.disabled = true;
    const enable = buttons.filter(but => but.disabled).length === buttons.length;
    document.getElementById("answer").disabled = !enable
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="apagaDiv">
  <button data-type="smart" class="apaga" type="button">Smart</button>
  <button data-type="mobile" class="apaga" type="button">Mobile</button>
  <button data-type="cell" class="apaga" type="button">Cell</button>
</div>
<button type="button" class="resolve center-block" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" id="answer" disabled>Answer the question</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an if statement to check if your first three buttons are disabled. If so, enable the fourth button. Example:

```
if( document.getElementById("mobile").disabled &&
document.getElementById("cell").disabled &&
document.getElementById("smart").disabled ){
    document.getElementById("answer").disabled = false;
}
```

Comment: No need to use if when setting a boolean